# Difference between quantiles of different random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

Let $Q_{\alpha}(X)$ for $\alpha \in (0,1)$ be the $\alpha$-th quantile of the random variable $X$. Suppose that $X$ and another random variable $Y$ (independent of $X$) have nice continuous (or maybe even smooth) densities. Can I get an upper bound on the difference:
$$
\left| Q_{\alpha}(X+Y)- Q_{\alpha}(X) \right|
$$
in terms of the densities of $X$ and $Y$?

Answer (score 1):

**Basic Approach.** Note that we can write

$$
Q_\alpha(X) = F_X^{-1}(\alpha)
$$

where $F_X(x) \equiv P(X < x)$ is the cumulative distribution function (CDF) of $X$.  So the expression in the absolute value is

$$
F_{X+Y}^{-1}(\alpha)-F_X^{-1}(\alpha)
$$

where the corresponding PDF

$$
f_{X+Y} = f_X \ast f_Y
$$

That is, $f_{X+Y}$ is the convolution of $f_X$ and $f_Y$.  (Thanks to A.S. in the comments for catching this, and shame on me for not noticing for over four years!)

Does that help?  Or do you need something more specific?

Comment: But $F_{X+Y}\neq F_X*F_Y$. pdfs, not cdfs, convolute.

Comment: @A.S.: I'm astounded that I didn't see this comment (or the mistake that precipitated it).  Thanks for the catch, and I'll edit.